# Why position:absolute image enables scroll bar?

Tags: css

I have an image at the top of the page as background. It should be width:100% when screen is big and do not minimize less than 1000px, but also, do not enable scroll bar when screen is smaller than 1000px - `but it enables it`. How to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
<img alt="Bg1" src="/assets/bg1.png" style="width:100%; min-width:1000px; 
min-height:600px; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:-1" />
```

UPDATED:
jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/c982gko9/

PS it always should be at the top of the page, so position:fixed can't be used...

Comment: encapsulate it in a div and add `overflow:hidden;` or make a jsFiddle so I can look into it.

Comment: here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/c982gko9/

Comment: it always should be at the top of the page, so position:fixed can't be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have to add an `<img>` tag, **semantically** you are using the picture as background, it should be background as well!

Here is a solution, it is adaptive and still can keep the resolution ratio of your picture:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.overlay div {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-image: url(http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but on smaller screen image will be smaller - I need to make it at least 1000px wide - so users will see only the corner of it

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c982gko9/1/)

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

Most major browsers have a default 8px margin (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/c982gko9/2/

Create a wrapper div for image. As you can not tell image not to scroll

Remove position: absolute from image and make overflow: hidden for the wrapper div.

```
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```